# Dj JWebBrowser Compatibility view Linked with Internet Explorer

Tags: java, intranet, jwebbrowser

I created an Intranet Site that I want to run in a Java Application using JWebBrowser.

When I run my application in IE, it assumes because it is on Intranet, It must be run on compatibility view. I also noticed using JWebBrowser that it is the same way. (in compatibility view nothing works, it is terrible)

I can easily change it so it isn't in compatibility view by going in IE -> Tools -> Compatibility View Settings -> uncheck "display all intranet applications in compatibility view".

Once I uncheck this, it works fine in JWebBrowser (it seems that JWebBrowser is linked with IE).

I don't want to have to uncheck this for every computer the application is run on.

is there a way I can make it so this isn't dependent on IE's settings? Or is there a way I can change the settings via java code?

Answer (score 0):

I think the compatibility mode meta-tag may help:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/cc817574.aspx